# Optimal Packing of Seven Circles in a Square

Tags: geometry

> Seven identical non-overlapping circles are placed in a square.  What is the largest circle possible?

The best arrangement I can find is:

[image]

If the square has a side of 1, the radius of a circle is 1/(4 + √3) = 0.1744+.

Comment: must all circles have the same radius?

Comment: There must be some more conditions....

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_packing_in_a_square

Answer (score 1):

The packing you show was proved by J. Schaer in 1964; see [this link](https://erich-friedman.github.io/packing/cirinsqu/), and [this paper](http://www.scivis.ethz.ch/publications/pdf/1994/wuertz1994history.pdf) for secondary references.

Comment: Thanks for the web references.  Didn't realize this was a well-studied problem.